# Django: Is there a way to reaggregate the Sum after search?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

Currently in my **ListView** there's a filtering that only shows the data of the current month and year and it aggregates the **Sum**. Now, in my filtering there are three problems.

1st problem; The filter can only show the current month and year, no way for the user to view the previous month and year.

2nd problem; The search filter for the **date__icontains** only accepts a numerical value of the months.

3rd problem; After I've added a search filter for a certain month the filter doesn't re-aggregate the **Sum**.

This is my PayrollView

```
class PayrollView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'payroll/payroll.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        user = request.user.staffs.full_name
        current_month = datetime.date.today().month
        current_year = datetime.date.today().year
        payroll_list = VaPayroll.objects.all()
        payroll_data = payroll_list.filter(Q(virtual_assistant__name=user),
                                           Q(date__month=current_month))
        total_salary = VaPayroll.objects.filter(Q(virtual_assistant__name=user), 
                                                Q(date__month=current_month), 
                                                Q(date__year=current_year)).aggregate(Sum('salary'))
        if search:
            payroll_data = payroll_list.filter(Q(virtual_assistant__name=user),
                                               Q(date__icontains=search))

            payroll_data
        context = {
            'total_salary': total_salary,
            'payroll_data': payroll_data
        }   
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

How can I achieve a result that will aggregate the sum after each search based on a certain month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, I've just added the total_salary in the if statement of **search** and replaced the **date__month=current_month** with **date__month=search**